# Can you do html form pagination based on screen size? if so how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

for example I have 30 questions to ask it will display like 3 pages on a laptop but 10 on a mobile can we do this? with a next button ofcourse

Comment: Needs further UI considering: have you considered the case when the screen size changes BETWEEN pages? Users can always resize the viewport on a computer and that would be a very confusing experience.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While we are willing to help you with your problem, could you please edit your question to contain a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example? We require this for debugging questions because 1) this makes it a lot easier for us to fiddle around on the actual problem, and 2) will, if solved, add to the knowledge base of Stack Overflow, so that other people with the same problem can find a solution here or learn from it.

Comment: Scrolling isn't an evil UI feature.

Answer (score 1):

You may read the browser width and think of a threshold like 600 as to define mobile or desktop usage.
Considering this solution as a client-side pagination using jQuery:

```js
var current_width = $(window).width();
if(current_width<600) pageSize = 3;
if(current_width>600) pageSize = 10;

showPage = function(page) {
    $(".question").hide();
    $(".question").each(function(n) {
        if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
            $(this).show();
    });        
}
    
showPage(1);

$("#pagination a").click(function() {
    $("#pagination a").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    showPage(parseInt($(this).text())) 
});
```

```css
.question {
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #565656;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

#pagination {
  list-style: none;
  width:200px;
  margin:10px auto;
}
#pagination li {
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
}
#pagination a {
  display:block;
  color:#787878;
  padding:5px 8px;
  border-radius:3px;
  background:#f9f9f9;
}
#pagination a.current {
  color:white;
  background:#8989ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=""questions">
  <div class="question">1 I have some first question</div>
  <div class="question">2 I have some second question</div>
  <div class="question">3 I have some third question</div>
  <div class="question">4 I have some forth question</div>
  <div class="question">5 I have some fifth question</div>
  <div class="question">6 I have some sixth question</div>
  <div class="question">7 I have some seventh question</div>
  <div class="question">8 I have some eighth question</div>
  <div class="question">9 I have some ninth question</div>
  <div class="question">10 I have some tenth question</div>
  <div class="question">11 I have some eleventh question</div>
  <div class="question">12 I have some twelveth question</div>
</div>
<ul id="pagination">
  <li><a class="current" href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ul>
```